# Docker do not use cache on Docker Tools on MacOS ElCapitan

Tags: macos, docker, caching, docker-compose

Using Docker-tools on MacOS ElCapitan, when I run `docker build .` or `docker build -f Dockerfile .` more than one time it rebuilds everything again and do not use the cache. With `docker-compose build .` is the same thing.

When I run it on Debian it works fine, with the cache. Maybe someone had the same problem, please share their solution .

Comment: Doesn't it reuse any layer or it stops "using cache" in a specific layer?

Comment: it doesn't "using cache" just after install Docker-tools

Comment: What is exactly 'Docker-tools'?

Comment: Docker-tools it is app for using Docker on MacOS. For some of macs which don't support 'Docker for Mac' application. It old macs or  macs with specific hardwair like Xeon processors etc.

Comment: I don't get your point about the 'using cache'. My question was about the output of `docker build`, if you see any 'using cache' or you don't see it at all. 'Docker Toolbox' is supposed to be already installed (nothing that you repeat over the time)

Comment: @Robert thanks for editing grammar in my question

Comment: yes, 'using cache' in output, but it don't use it for real